# Periodic tile update

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm developing an application, that allows using dictionaries (e.g. English-German). I want to enable periodic tile updates for my application at start screen. I want to show random word with translation from random dictionary, so all I want to do is just show 2 strings (I found an appropriate template for it). I can show the notification once using  `TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().AddToSchedule()`
but I want it to happen say every minute. I only found examples that use  `TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().StartPeriodicUpdate()` method and they all use some web address. Is there any way to make it happen using just my local strings without accessing cloud or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For showing periodic tile updates periodically *when your app is not running* you need to provide a URL that will be requested every once in a while (I don't think you can set it to as frequent as 1 minute though - I think the least is 15 minutes.).

If your app is in the foreground, you can simply run a timer and show an update every minute.

You could use push notifications, but again - that's more complex than just providing a URL that returns the XML for a tile update.

In case you want to look at the possibilities: http://blog.equinoxe-consulting.net/blog/bard-rsquo-s-tile-i-introduction-and-local-tiles-and-badges

Comment: Thanks for answer. I thought I could do something similar to Bing Travel or Bing News (their tiles are updated quite often, though I didn't launch them). However updating tiles only when my app is running is OK for me

Comment: I think the Bing apps use push notifications - so they work without the app running. You can still do that - except it is a little more involved :)

Comment: The Bing apps enable the notification queue (or cycling) to appear as if their tile is updated quite often.  With the notification queue enabled and multiple tile updates, Windows will automatically cycle through the up to 5 updates every few seconds giving the appearance of new content.  New updates for the Bing News app are delivered relatively infrequently using periodic updates.  A few suggestions for your app: 1) Use periodic updates, 2) Enable cycling, and provide 5 updates each time your app is made visible, or 3) Provide multiple daily updates using scheduled tile notifications.

Comment: @Krishna sorry for being that noob, but by "providing an URL" you mean you mandatory have to call an external webservice or could that be a URL pointing to some ressource inside your own app ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @freeeman 'providing a URL' means setting the property to a valid URL that points to a working webservice that will return the appropriate XML for the tile update. This means you will need to create and host a publicly accessible webservice. The tile notification system built into Windows 8 will call the URL for you when it needs to show an update.

Comment: @Krishna thanks for your answer, yes I kinda thought that it would be mandatory. Thanks for the clarification